# How to order Vaadin Table Rows?

Tags: java, sql, vaadin

I have a table **phases** that has values that reference to a **repository** table. In the repository each value has an order number.

Normally in SQL, I would join them and then order by the order column. But if I want to do that in Vaadin I have to use the `FreeFormQuery` to make this join.

The Problem is that I want to allow users to change values in the table **phases**. So I would need to implement the `FreeFormQueryDelegate`. Is there a way to make this work by using a standard `TableQuery` instead of a `FreeFormQuery` ?

Maybe manually move the rows in a table ?

Answer (score 15):

Vaadin offers some sort options for tables.

You can sort one specific propertyId or you can sort a set of properties.

```
// sort one container property Id
table.setSortContainerPropertyId(propertyId);
table.setSortAscending(ascending);
table.sort();

// sort several property Ids
table.sort(propertyId[], ascending[]);
```

NOTE: the code above is no proper code, it rather shows the method bodies.

Comment: FYI: this only works with plain column names, you need a different approach if your order by clause has any kind of complex expression (e.g. ORDER BY column1/column2)

Answer (score 0):

I used follow code to rearrange the vaadin table rows, when "Move Up" button click, while selecting a table row.

```
Object selectedItemId = fieldTable.getValue();
        if(selectedItemId != null){
            List<Object> items = new ArrayList<>(fieldTable.getItemIds());
            int index = items.indexOf(selectedItemId);

            if(index < 1){
                LOGGER.info("Selected Filed is at the top, cannot move up further");
                return;
            }

            //Rearrange itemids for new order
            Object upperRow= items.set(index - 1, selectedItemId);
            items.set(index, upperRow);

            items.forEach(itemId -> {
                //Gets the properties of old table item
                Item item = fieldTable.getItem(itemId);
                String name = (String) item.getItemProperty(Constants.PROPERTYID_FIELD_NAME).getValue();
                Button toggleBtn = (Button) item.getItemProperty(Constants.PROPERTYID_SORT_BUTTON).getValue();

                //Remove the old table item
                fieldTable.removeItem(itemId);

                //Insert old table item into the new position index
                Item newItem = fieldTable.addItem(itemId);
                newItem.getItemProperty(Constants.PROPERTYID_FIELD_NAME).setValue(name);
                newItem.getItemProperty(Constants.PROPERTYID_SORT_BUTTON).setValue(toggleBtn);

                int position = items.indexOf(itemId);
                if(position == index - 1) {
                    fieldTable.select(itemId);
                }
            });
        }
```